# How to display a query results from Open CMIS, Alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, ecm

Newcomer to Alfresco and Web Development here, so bear with me. I've so far installed Alfresco and was able to use the Maven AMP archetype to create my own custom content model for the data I need to store in it. Now I need to access this data from an external site by querying the Alfresco repository.

I've followed what I can find on CMIS and was able to execute a query using curl and get the results I expect in a large XML stream. My colleague was having an uphill battle trying to interpret these results using Coldfusion. Now I searched around, and understand that to interpret these results and make the process a bit easier, it is better to use some kind of client like Open CMIS (or Chemistry, I'm still a bit confused on the terminology here).

We've so far tried the the PHP client, but received some errors from the xmlLoad function not reading 'nbsp' characters. PHP seemed like the easiest version to implement, though we're considering moving to Java if that works better. However, we've seen very scarce documentation on either end. Are there some better examples that we may have missed or maybe some other way to do this? Seems like this should be simple to implement, yet it's given us quite the stall due to the brick wall that Alfresco and CMIS seem to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a library, the CMIS Browser Binding might work better for you. It returns JSON instead of XML.

Try:

```
http://<host>/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser?cmisselector=query&succinct=true&q=SELECT * FROM cmis:document
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a brick wall at all. Here are some resources:

- The [custom content types tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html) has a section on CMIS,
  including CMIS queries which may be helpful to you even if you do not need custom types
- The [CMIS & Apache Chemistry](http://manning.com/mueller/) book from
  Manning is a good resource (disclosure: Florian and I co-authored it
  along with another colleague, Jay Brown)
- There are some [Java examples](https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-api-java-examples/) on Google Code
- There are additional resources and helpful links on the [Alfresco CMIS](http://www.alfresco.com/cmis) page